# CakePHP Model Associations

Tags: php, cakephp, php4, cakephp-bake

Here's the deal, i have 2 models: Rus and Audios. I want to use records from Audios in Rus controller, so i go and type in associations like this:

```
<?
class Rus extends AppModel
{
var $name = 'Ru';
var $hasMany = 'Audio';
}
?>
```

and

```
<?
class Audios extends AppModel
{
var $name = 'Audio';
var $belongsTo = 'Ru';
}
?>
```

when i use scaffol feature nothing works. help please.

Comment: elaborate *nothing works*. Error? Unexpected functionality? a blank page?

Comment: i dont get the associations i need.

Comment: not helping. Do your tables have the necessary `ru_id` and `audio_id` fields?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.

ru.php:

```
<?
class Ru extends AppModel
{
var $name = 'Ru';
var $hasMany = 'Audio';
}
?>
```

audio.php

```
<?
class Audio extends AppModel
{
var $name = 'Audio';
var $belongsTo = 'Ru';
}
?>
```

Your model names should be singular.